# net::ERR_ABORTED when trying to use my javascript file inside my html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Whenever I call my `index.html` that is served by my `node.js` server along with my *styles, images and script* files I get this **net::ERR_ABORTED** error for my javascript file included in the html.

This is my code in my html file to include my js file:

```
<script src="../jsfiles/getData.js"></script>
```

and I'm using this code on my server side to include them:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'pages')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'styles')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'jsfiles')));
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
PongWebServer
-- pages
-- images
-- styles
-- jsfiles
```

I would appreciate any help, I'm stuck for over an hour now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not put them all in one folder named `public` and make that `static`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know in which directory your index file is.
but what i can assume is that your directory may look like,

```
PongWebServer
 -- pages
 -- images
 -- styles
 -- jsfiles
-index.html
```

If something like this then you have to call your javascript file as

```
<script src="/jsfiles/getData.js"></script>
```

While you are using `..` will go back to one path and will find for your `jsfiles` and that will not be thare.

Comment: i forgot to mention that my index.html is in my pages folder.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is caused because you're serving `index.html` and `text/html` for every single request. So, when the browser asks for `/getData.js`, your serving is sending it `index.html` and `text/html`.

Comment: can i solve this problem by putting all the files in a public folder and serving the whole public folder?

Comment: if the javascript file is not having so much of line you can put it in `<script>//js code </script>` in your `index.html` file.